# Can be summation of numbers in a set considered its measure?

Tags: measure-theory

I have for example following sets:

\begin{align}
A &= \{1,2\}\\
B &= \{3,4\}
\end{align}

Now I would define my measure as a summation of all the numbers in a set, so:

\begin{align}
\mu(A) &= 1+2 = 3\\
\mu(B) &= 3+4 = 7
\end{align}

As far as I know, any correct measure must comply with following conditions:

- $\mu \not\equiv \infty$
- if $A,B \in \mathbb A$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset: \mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$

---

So, let's say, that my sets $A,B$ belong to some $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb A$. Then we can see, that:

\begin{align}
A\cup B &= \{1,2\} \cup \{3,4\} = \{1,2,3,4\}\\
\mu(A) + \mu(B) &= 10 = \mu(A \cup B)
\end{align}

According to this, a summation of elements in sets should be a correct measure. Is my reasoning correct or do I understand it wrong?

Comment: Often when talking about measures we are talking about $\sigma$-additive measures, and finitely additive measures have their finite additivity mentioned explicitly (the second condition you mention is just finite additivity, but still later you talk about $\sigma$-algebras). Note this is not a problem here, though. One thing that you didn't mention, however, is what sets are you measuring? Integers, natural numbers, reals, complex numbers? What exactly is the underlying set?

Comment: Not to mention that *every* set belongs to some $\sigma$-algebra, along with other sets where addition does not make sense.  So you should specify, in a very concrete way, what is your $\sigma$-algebra, which includes also specifying what type of sets you are measuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your set function $\mu$ defines a legitimate measure *provided* your sample space contains only nonnegative reals; otherwise you violate the requirement that $\mu(A)\ge0$ for every $A$. See the Discussion in this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure, which notes that the set function $\mu$ defined by
$$\mu(A):=\sum_{x\in A}f(A)$$
defines a measure for any function $f$ mapping your sample space $X$ to the nonnegative reals; the sigma-algebra would be the collection of all subsets of $X$. For example $f(x):=x$ works if $X\subset \mathbb R$ is a subset of the nonnegative reals; if $X\subset \mathbb R$ contains negative reals then $f(x):=|x|$ defines a measure. (If $f(x):=1$ then we recover counting measure.)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add this requirement into my description... So, if I defined, that elements in my sets belong to $\mathbb R^{+}_{0}$, would it be ok? Or if I redefined my measure as the sum of absolute values of elements?

Comment: @Eenoku Yes, if the mapping $\mu$ sends every singleton to a nonnegative number, then you've got a measure. See the cited article.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you, please, add these examples into your answer, so I could accept it? I think it could be helpful for somebody...